# What's the order of the pixel components returned by Raster.getPixels()?

Tags: java, awt, java-2d

I've written image processing code that copies the pixel data into integer array like this:

```
void processImage(BufferedImage source) {

    WritableRaster raster = source.getRaster();
    int numBands = raster.getNumBands();
    int height = raster.getHeight();
    int width = raster.getWidth();

    int[] pixelRow = new int[width * numBands];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        raster.getPixels(raster.getMinX(), raster.getMinY() + i, width, 1, pixelRow);

        // do some processing
    }

    // create a new image
    return newImage;
}
```

The code works with the images I've tested so far. The `pixelRow` array seems to always receive the pixel components in the order Red, Green and Blue for images with 3 bands (no alpha channel) and in the order Red, Green, Blue and Alpha for those with 4 bands (with alpha channel).

However, I cannot find any description that states this. Is it guaranteed that I will always get the pixel components in that order? Is there any specification that describes this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `SampleModel.getPixel()` (used internally by the `Raster.getPixel()`) returns pixel components in the order of bands. While it is possible to create a bogus instance of `SampleModel` programmatically with the band order different from the RGB, usually instances of the `SampleModel`s are created by some `ColorModel` which constructs the `SampleModel` with bands in the same order as the order of color components in the `ColorModel`.

The order of color model components is documented in the [java.awt.image.ColorModel javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorModel.html):

> The number, order, and interpretation of color components for a `ColorModel` is specified by its `ColorSpace`.

In theory you should check whether the color space is from the RGB family:

```
public static void processImage( BufferedImage source )
{
    ColorSpace colorSpace = source.getColorModel().getColorSpace();
    if ( dumpColorSpaceProperties ) {
        System.out.printf( "color space type: %d, is RGB = %s%n", colorSpace.getType(), colorSpace.isCS_sRGB() );
        for ( int i = 0; i < colorSpace.getNumComponents(); i++ ) {
            System.out.printf( "component %d = %s%n", i, colorSpace.getName( i ) );
        }
    }

    if ( colorSpace.getType() == ColorSpace.TYPE_RGB ) {
        // guaranteed RGB(A) order, proceed with raster.getPixels()
    } else {
        // well, find a way to convert from that space into RGB
        throw new AssertionError( "color space type = " + colorSpace.getType() );
    }
}
```

In practice it all depends on the source of the image. Images created via `BufferedImage(width, height, imageType)` always use RGB space. Images obtained from a file can use some other color space if the image file format supports different color space and if that particular image file uses non-RGB space.

If you know the image source you do not need to check the color space and you can assume the RGB(A) output from the `Raster.getPixels()`.

The `ColorSpace.getName(int)` source provides insight into default components for most color sets that can be encountered in practice.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. That looks very good. For CMYK JPEG images, I convert the colorspace into RGB right before the image processing code that calls getPixels(). That would perfectly fit.

Answer (score 1):

A `Raster` object includes a `SampleModel`.
The SampleModel describes the pixel layout within the Raster object.

Here are some links:

- [Raster JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/Raster.html)
- [SampleModel JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/SampleModel.html)

Comment: Thanks for the links. These two classes provide a lot of information, e.g. whether the colors are stored in separate planes, what data types are in use. It's mainly information that I don't need to care about because *getPixels()* conveniently unpacks the color components into an easy to use array. However, I cannot figure out what method would give me more information about the order of the color components. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

This document [PNG Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#3Definitions) seems to suggest that the order you described is, in fact, standard. Section 3.1.44 implies as much. However, in other cases involving colors it seems the usual is [alpha,] red, green, blue as described by [Microsoft here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) Seeing as several methods in classes of the java.awt.image package use or return a similar array of samples, it should be pretty safe to assume that this order is standard. Despite this, I could not find one instance where this behaviour was specified.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I'm specifically interested in the output of Java's *Raster.getPixels()* and not how it's stored in a PNG file or handled in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the definitive answer either. But the relevant information is more likely found in the [ColorModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorModel.html) instance (rather than in the Raster or SampleModel instances).

The *ColorModel* instance is directly accessible from the *BufferedImage*.